# Что быстрее чтение из файла или запрос в базу данных?

Tags: python, база-данных

Реализую бота в телеграмме, из-за этого критически важно быстродействие.
Словарь со значениями лучше писать в файл с серилизацией через модуль pickle или подумать над работой с базой данных. Если возможно то опишите преимущества того и другого

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретной ситуации. Берёте оба варианта, измеряете оба варианта и сравниваете

Comment: Вопрос класса "Стометровку быстрее пробежит инженер или слесарь?"

Comment: Зависит от размера данных. При небольших размерах "интернет" будет наиболее медленной частью. И, на всякий случай, удобная запись из питона в файл идет через модуль `shelve`, который, правда, и использует внутри `pickle`.

Comment: @AlexTitov тогда бы сервер memcached не существовал в природе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря сколько байт итого за 1 запрос.
Сериализация не будет на быстрая при нормальном весе файла. Я сериализую только небольшие части из БД, которые очень часто запрашиваются.